nginx: restrict proxied IP access except Cloudflare edge servers?
We are using cloudflare proxy, so real IP is hidden. But if you would know real IP, you can still access site using it. Is there a way to limit access by that IP?
I mean:

by domain: https://some-domain.com -> OK
by proxy IP: https://1.2.3.4 -> OK
by real IP: https://5.6.7.8 -> to restrict.

Or it is pointless to try to restrict it?
Sample of nginx.conf server blocks:
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name some-domain.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    charset utf-8;
    server {
        server_name some-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ...
        ...
    }


I've added an important addition to the answer that I forgot to make earlier, regarding the combined use of the geo and set_real_ip_from directives (see edit history).

@IvanShatsky thanks for clarification

You are mixing two different things here. The first is restricting access for clients that do not have the correct Host header set in their requests (these are usually bots, network scanners, etc.). To achieve this, you need some kind of a catch-all server block to deny such requests. Refer to this StackOverflow answer for examples.
The second is restricting requests with the correct Host header but originating from sources other than Cloudflare edge servers. This is generally a good practice since Cloudflare acts as an anti-DDoS (and possibly WAF) service for your site. The official Cloudflare IP ranges list is available on their website: IP Ranges, or in plain text at IPv4 and IPv6 web addresses. You can use this list to deny such requests using the ngx_http_geo_module as follows:
geo $denied {
    default 1;
    173.245.48.0/20 0;
    103.21.244.0/22 0;
    ...
}
server {
    server_name some-domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    if ($denied) {
        # terminate request immediately
        return 444;
    }
    ...

The IP ranges list is updated periodically, so I use the following script to generate the list of ranges automatically:
#!/bin/sh
{
  echo "# Cloudflare IP ranges - generated on $(date)"
  curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4/ | sed 's/$/ 0;/'
  echo # just an empty line
  curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6/ | sed 's/$/ 0;/'
  echo # just another empty line
} > /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc

You can then include this list in your nginx configuration as follows:
geo $denied {
    default 1;
    include cloudflare.inc;
    # you can add some extra IP addresses here
    # (as I sometimes do adding my home/work IPs)
}

You can also use the IP ranges list to restore the original visitor IPs (see the "Restoring original visitor IPs" official Cloudflare article for details). Actually, nowadays I use another script to automatically generate two files:
#!/bin/bash
echo "# Cloudflare IP ranges - generated on $(date)" | tee /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc > /etc/nginx/real_ip.inc
curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4/ | tee >(sed 's/$/ 0;/' >> /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc) | sed 's/^/set_real_ip_from /; s/$/;/' >> /etc/nginx/real_ip.inc
echo >> /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc # Empty line for cloudflare.inc
echo >> /etc/nginx/real_ip.inc    # Empty line for real_ip.inc
curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6/ | tee >(sed 's/$/ 0;/' >> /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc) | sed 's/^/set_real_ip_from /; s/$/;/' >> /etc/nginx/real_ip.inc
echo >> /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc # Another empty line for cloudflare.inc
echo >> /etc/nginx/real_ip.inc    # Another empty line for real_ip.inc

The second file will contain records in the following format:
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
...

You can use this file as follows:
server {
    server_name some-domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    if ($denied) {
        # terminate request immediately
        return 444;
    }
    include real_ip.inc;
    real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
    ...

There can be cases where this setup is necessary (here is an issue I once ran upon). However, if you use such a configuration, keep in mind that the $remote_addr variable, which is used by default in the geo block to check whether an IP address matches the specified ranges, will no longer contain the Cloudflare edge server address. Instead, you will need to explicitly specify the $realip_remote_addr variable:
geo $realip_remote_addr $denied {
    default 1;
    include cloudflare.inc;
    ...
}

